# Pinyin-based input method with tones for Taiwanese Mandarin in Windows

Tags: traditional-characters, taiwan, input-methods

I am looking for a Pinyin-based input method for traditional characters on Windows, that allows me to force selecting the tone for learning purposes.
E.g. entering le4 se4 should give 垃圾.
Does something like this exist? Most methods for Taiwanese Mandarin seem to be either Zhuyin-based or just require the pinyin without tones.

Comment: Even in Mainland China, input methods for simplified Chinese don't care about the tone. Honestly, I don't know a single input method that is at least slightly widely used that takes tones into consideration.

Comment: To be honest, I dont know if it really has utility either. The morphological constructions of characters far outweigh their specific tones in rapid text selection from IMEs.

Comment: I remember there are keyboard settings for changing Zhuyin or Loma("羅馬拼音") in the old Windows Zhuyin IM (Windows 98/ME/2000), maybe you can find it in the new Windows Zhuyin IM too?

Comment: @MMZK1526 Zhuyin input methods take tones into consideration and I can see the utility for helping one remember the tones for characters.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I know is 地球拼音 with rime, which is an input method engine. You can input traditional characters with pinyin and tone. But I think it follows the traditional Chinese character orthography on Chinese mainland. As you know, Chinese mainland, Hong Kong Macau, and Taiwan have different orthographies for traditional characters, though the difference is minor.

For rime, you can download it from its official website https://rime.im/. It comes in Windows, Mac and Linux versions. 地球拼音 is one of its default input schemas.

Here’s an article from the author of the schema (https://byvoid.com/zhs/blog/recommend-rime/) with screenshots of 帶聲調的拼音輸入法.

I strongly recommend rime. It offers wonderfully many possibilities for inputting, especially for Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

A previous commenter mentioned using 地球拼音 (also called terra-pinyin) with rime, which is an input method engine.

Here's how I got this to work on Mac:

- Install [squirrel](https://rime.im) (that's the name of rime for Mac)
- In terminal: Run `curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rime/plum/master/rime-install | zsh`
- In Keyboard -> Input Sources: Add squirrel as an input source, this will be listed under Chinese, Simplified
- Switch to Squirrel as your input
- Press F4, scroll down and select 地球拼音
- Start typing Chinese! To enter a tone, use - / < \ to indicate the tone.